# How do I determine what version of the Azure Function runtime I'm using locally?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I've download azure-functions-core-tool@3 and when I run a newly created function project using the Azure Tools it appears to be running v2, though I'm not sure .

The `settings.json` file is the following:

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
  "azureFunctions.postDeployTask": "npm install",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "JavaScript",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "npm prune"
}
```

However, when I run the Azure functions with "npm start" or "func start", the header portion reports:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.2184 Commit hash: 5afacc827c2848e4debc23bb96604f1ffce09cc7)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12961.0
```

and later in the log I see:

```
[warn] The Node.js version you are using (v12.17.0) is not fully supported by Azure Functions V2. We recommend using one the following major versions: 8, 10.
```

which seems to imply that the functions are still running in a 2.0 mode.

How can you determine which version of the runtime is executing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see

> Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12961.0

you're running runtime V2.

Run `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3` to explicitly install the V3 runtime and you'll be running V3 locally.

[image: Azure Functions runtim V3]

> **Version 2.x and 3.x**
>   Version 2.x/3.x of the tools uses the Azure Functions runtime that is built on .NET Core. This version is supported on all platforms .NET Core supports, including Windows, macOS, and Linux.

More information: [Work with Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)

Comment: I've install core-tools@3 several times now and it still runs v2 instead.

Comment: Apparently I had a copy of v2 installed with Chocolatey and it was overriding the one installed with npm.